# Pandas changes values in associated array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I found a strange behaviour of pandas. It seems that pandas implicitly changes values inside the column which contain numpy.array. It happened when the column is used to index something and contains negative values. Those values are changed to its bitwise not (~). To reproduce the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([-1,1,2]),
    np.array([-1,2,0]),
    np.array([0,2,1,-1])]


dc = {'numbers':[0,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dc)
df['arr'] = a 

df
   numbers            arr
0        0     [-1, 1, 2]
1        1     [-1, 2, 0]
2        2  [0, 2, 1, -1]
```

but after operation like this:

```py
df.iloc[df.iloc[0].arr]
```

we have a change:

```py
   numbers            arr
0        0      [2, 1, 2]
1        1     [-1, 2, 0]
2        2  [0, 2, 1, -1]
```

-1 in the first row change into 2 which is perfectly OK for indexing (-1 index is 2 in the three-element list) but the value was physically changed what definitely is not OK. it seems when the array is used as a list of indexes values are changed and remain changed.

pandas version: 0.23.4, and 0.25.0
numpy version: 1.16.4 and 1.17.0

Seems like a bug?

Comment: ok, cant reproduce this in pandas `0.24.2` , i get `[array([ 0,  2,  1, -1]), array([-1,  2,  0]), array([ 0,  2,  1, -1])]` which is fine

Comment: is not fine: first row is 0, 2, 1, -1 shoud be [-1,1,2]

Comment: why? `-1` defaults to `2` (the last index) which has value `[ 0, 2, 1, -1]` in the `arr` column

Comment: well it seems one line of code is missing. This bizarre results happens **after** running df.iloc. Just type *df* again affter running *df.iloc[df.iloc[0].arr]* and look that values in arr column (and a list as well) has changed. -1 was converted into 2 which should not happened for no reason

Comment: so i printed `df.iloc[df.iloc[0].arr] ` and printed `df` , it gave me the original df back, no changes

Comment: so it means that your version of pandas/numpy works fine on your os, ie. .iloc does not change negative indexes into positives in place. In versions mentioned by me, problem remains.